# MySQL to JSON, how to get the right format?

Tags: php, mysql, json

So, I'm using a PHP-script to output MySQL to JSON, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to output the right JSON-format.

**Here's the PHP-script:**

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM DiseaseData"; 
$res_sql = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
$arr = array();


if(mysql_num_rows($res_sql) > 0){   

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    while($row_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_sql)){

        $arr[] =  $row_sql;

        }
        $json = json_encode($arr);
        $file = '../../files/json/DiseaseData.json';
        file_put_contents($file, $json);

    }  
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

**Here's the outputted JSON-format:**

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "Magnitude": "0.842",
    "County": "Alameda",
    "Disease": "E. coli O157",
    "lat": "37.7652",
    "lng": "-122.242"
}, {
    "ID": "2",
    "Magnitude": "1.520",
    "County": "Alameda",
    "Disease": "HIV",
    "lat": "37.7652",
    "lng": "-122.242"
}]
```

**This is the JSON-format I'd like to have it in:**

```
{
    "columns":[{
            "fieldName" : "ID",
            "position" : 1
    },
    {
            "fieldName" : "Magnitude",
            "position" : 2
    },
    {
            "fieldName" : "County",
            "position" : 3
    },
    {
            "fieldName" : "Disease",
            "position" : 4
    },
    {
            "fieldName" : "lat",
            "position" : 5
    },
    {
            "fieldName" : "lng",
            "position" : 6
    },]
    "data": [ 
        [ 1, 0.842, "Alameda", "E. coli O157", 37.7652, -122.242],
        [ 2, 1.520, "Alameda", "HIV", 37.7652, -122.242]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be like this:

- Create two arrays, `$columns` and `$data`
- In `$columns` array, store the position and the associated field name
- In `$data` array, insert all data rows using `while` loop.
- Finally, insert both the arrays in `$result` array and then apply `json_enocde()` on it.

Here's the code:

```
// your code

if(mysql_num_rows($res_sql) > 0){   
    $columns = $data = array();
    $max_columns = mysql_num_fields($res_sql);

    for($i=0; $i < $max_columns; $i++){
         $columns[] = array('fieldName' => mysql_field_name($res_sql, $i), 'position' => $i+1);
    }

    while($row_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_sql)){
        $data[] =  array_values($row_sql);
    }
    $result = array('columns' => $columns, 'data' => $data);
    $json = json_encode($result);

    // your code  
}
```

---

**Note:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working like charm! 

Only thing was that the column "ID" returned boolean "false" in the outputted JSON and the columns switched position.

`"columns": [{
  "fieldName": "Magnitude",
  "position": 1
 }, {
  "fieldName": "County",
  "position": 2
 }, {
  "fieldName": "Disease",
  "position": 3
 }, {
  "fieldName": "lat",
  "position": 4
 }, {
  "fieldName": "lng",
  "position": 5
 }, {
  "fieldName": false,
  "position": 6
 }]`

Comment: @AdamDedanga Oh, that's because of the `for` loop, it should be `for($i=0; $i < $max_columns; $i++){...`, and instead of `'position' => $i`, it should be `'position' => $i+1`. I've updated my answer.